# Plotting Endpoints on a Piecewise Graph in Maple

Tags: maple

I am trying to plot a piecewise function in Maple and have the endpoints of each piece be an open circle or closed circle accordingly.  To define the function, I did:

`f := proc (x) options operator, arrow; piecewise(x <= -1, -2-x, -1 < x and x <= 1, 4-4*x^2, 1 < x, x^2-4*x+3);`

The to get a picture I did:

`plot(f(x), x = -4 .. 4, discont = true)`

I'd like to have the point $(-1,0)$, coming from the parabola, to have an open dot.  I can't figure out how to make that work.  I am brand new to Maple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case use:

> with(plottools):with(plots):
>   display(circle([-1, 0], 0.05, color = red), plot(f(x), x = -4 .. 4, discont = true));

Answer (score 2):

One potential issue with using `plottools:-circle` is that the shape can appear as an ellipse if, say, the displayed x- and y-views are not equal and the `scaling` is not `constrained`. (Eg. change the x-range to `x=-1.4 .. -0.9` to see this effect.)

Also, such a circle can get rendered a little roughly.

An alternative is to use `plottools:-point` and set the `symbol` to `circle` or `solidcircle`, which should render as circles regardless of the view or scaling.

You can even program it to compute the limits and value, etc.

```
restart:
with(plottools):with(plots):

f := x -> piecewise(x <= -1, -2-x,
                    -1 < x and x <= 1, 4-4*x^2,
                    1 < x, x^2-4*x+3):

setoptions(color="DarkRed", symbolsize=16, symbol=circle);

display(point([-1, limit(f(x),x=-1,right)]),
        point([-1, limit(f(x),x=-1,left)]),
        point([-1, f(-1)],  symbol=solidcircle),
        plot(f(x), x = -4 .. 4, discont = true));
```

In the above code a few plot options are set as new defaults, which can get overridden with optional arguments to the plotting commands. (Eg. `symbol=solidcircle`, when passed as an option, overrides the new default of `symbol=circle`.)